# Is there a way to enable hot reload for serverless offline when using caching?

Tags: caching, serverless

Serverless Offline was very slow so I enabled caching to avoid "cold starts". Now everything is slow just one time per lambda but for any code updates, I need to restart the dev env.

I use

```
serverless offline --config ./serverless-offline.yml --allowCache --functionCleanupIdleTimeSeconds 10000
```

Is there a plugin that I can set up and detect code updates and clear the whole cache without restarting? Maybe even just the lambda that was modified.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with nodemon you can achieve the same results.

npm i -D nodemon

And then in your start script:

"start": "nodemon --exec serverless offline"

That should work.

Best,

Comment: This just compile typescript file will not restart server.

Answer (score 1):

You might try reducing `--functionCleanupIdleTimeSeconds` to `5` and see if that helps, `10,000` is pretty high.

```
--functionCleanupIdleTimeSeconds ...Number of seconds until an idle function is eligible for cleanup
```

... meaning you'll be caching your source code for nearly three hours at 10,000 seconds.

Additionally, you may wish to do some extra debugging to see exactly where the slow-down is happening, in the code itself, DNS, host machine etc.

---

Edit: I started having errors with this while using Docker image `node:16`... so I migrated to Ubuntu 22.04 which solved my problem.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN \
    apt-get update &&\
    apt-get -y dist-upgrade &&\
    apt-get -y install curl &&\
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    apt-get -y install nodejs

RUN \
    npm install -g npm@8.19.1 &&\
    npm install -g serverless

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 3000
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is what you are looking for**

`serverless offline start --reloadHandler`